# CSS3 Gradients by pixel, instead of percentage

Tags: html, css

I'm wanting to create a linear gradient background, that fits the same no matter the size of the browser window, to accomodate a fixed-height header, sub-header, and content div.

My issue is I don't want the gradient to scale when I move the page around. I could use a 1px wide image to get the same result, I suppose, but I ultimately want the site to be as image-free as possible, barring the logo.

Is it possible to use a pixel-defined gradient instead of a percentage-defined gradient?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes you can. You can substitute standard units in place of the percentages. See this example:

http://dabblet.com/gist/1856111

```
background: linear-gradient(left, #729fcf 10px, #4c7bb4 20px, #3465a4 63%, #204a87 100%);
```

Comment: Works on that site, but not in practice. Neither Chrome nor Firefox render the gradient on my Mac...

Comment: @JonMitten dabblet renders without the prefixes. Sorry I've updated the sample to include them.

Comment: Great, this is perfect. Seems to work really well - however, I do notice the browser renders "jaggies" when the browser window is resized. This may be a result of the level of division I'm using. I don't believe it's distracting enough to matter too much.

Comment: I've removed the prefixes from the answer, as they are no longer needed nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. This really helped me create a gradient for some custom pages where a specific part of the gradient had to be aligned with specific content areas and then adjusted for various screen sizes on mobile

Answer (score 11):

If you need a fixed-size gradient, use the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property to specify its size.

Comment: This one is a good alternative too. Use `background-position` and `background-repeat` to fine tune.