# Top of background Transparent

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background

First, this is for the boxed part of a of a wordpress theme.
what i want to do is to make the top of the background transparent of 300px and the rest a #f2f2f2.
check this example:
background: linear-gradient(to top,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%,#33ccff 50%,#33ccff 100%);
i want it in pixels and not percentage

Comment: The background has to be of _SOME_ color. I think you need to give more details on what are you trying to archive.

Comment: edited the question for more details

Comment: Possible duplicate here: [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336846/css3-gradients-by-pixel-instead-of-percentage

Comment: was able to do it after some research fiddling

Answer (score 1):

After some research and editing I was able to get that sharp change in color.

Here is the answer :

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  transparent 0px,transparent 300px,#f2f2f2 300px,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  transparent 0px,transparent 300px,#f2f2f2 300px,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  transparent 0px,transparent 300px,#f2f2f2 300px,#f2f2f2 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,  transparent 0px,transparent 300px,#f2f2f2 300px,#f2f2f2 100%);
```

Comment: Well done on finding, and posting the answer. Exactly the way it should be done.